# Is there a way to automatically send push notifications without a server?(React Native)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

I'm working on a project to use the push notification function to users using the fcm service on the react native platform, and I've finished the test process to see if both the ios and Android environments are getting push notifications.

In the case of my project, I have implemented it to store and manage data only locally without a server.

It's a kind of diary application that uses a calendar, and when I record my diary on a specific date, I'm going to send a notification to users at 8 a.m. the next day

As for the format of simply sending fcm service without a server, I always want to send a regular notification at 8 o'clock, when the diary is recorded and then the next day. However, I want to use the method of sending it only on the next day when the diary is available.

Comment: Sending messages through FCM can only be done from a trusted environment. That has been covered quite regularly here, so I won't post a repeat answer. But... do you really need FCM here? Since your schedule is so regular, why not schedule a local task a few minutes before 8am that checks for relevant events on the server?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am currently developing only the app without separately developing a server.